# VLC Desktop mode spanning multiple monitors

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player, streaming

I have recently found out that VLC had a desktop mode and well i saw that some people was using this to have the ISS Livestream as their desktop background.

VLC was started inside Desktop Mode and the stream `http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8` loaded perfectly but instead of going on one screen its spans both of them, Is it posible to have it displayed on one monitor only instead of spanned across?.

Image: 
[image: Screenshot of what vlc looks like when used as desktop background]

Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Monitors: 1920x1080 and 1366x720

Comment: It's in "desktop mode" so it covers your whole _desktop_.   You should edit your question and tag it with the OS you're trying to accomplish this on.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Okay i added it, thanks for that - hopefully someone will have a idea what i'm rambling about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are to ways how you can fix it.

## 1. Using command line

Open `cmd.exe` and go to VLC path (it is usually in C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC).
Now run following command:

```
vlc --video-wallpaper --align=2 --qt-start-minimized http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8
```

This will start your stream in wallpaper mode `--video-wallpaper` and only with a systray icon `--qt-start-minimized` and will set the alignment of the video to the right screen `--align=2`.

For more help on command line options visit this [VLC Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)

> --align={0 (Center), 1 (Left), 2 (Right), 4 (Top), 8 (Bottom), 5 (Top-Left), 6 (Top-Right), 9 (Bottom-Left), 10 (Bottom-Right)}

## 2. Using GUI

Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, then select <kbd>All</kbd> in the *Show settings* group. This will show you whole bunch of available options. Then go to <kbd>Video</kbd> and search for <kbd>Video alignment</kbd> option. This options is set to *Center* by default. Change it to *Left* or *Right* in order to select your monitor in wallpaper mode. This worked for me. I hope it will do it for you too.

[image]

Comment: Using --align 10 and turning of desktop mode on and off again it worked perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: 10 - bottom right. Probably because you have different resolutions on both screens. But I'm glad it's working for you.